# How to delete items in cart with string

Tags: php, e-commerce

I have a shopping cart in my website that has uses a string for the shopping list. Each product has a 3 digit id, so the string looks something like 031181083 with 3 items.

In php,

```
session_start();
$numbooks = strlen($_SESSION['bookstrings'])/3;
$books = $_SESSION['cart'];
echo "You have " . $numbooks . " books in your Cart.";
echo $_SESSION['bookstrings'];
echo "<br><br>";
include '/redirect.php';
```

where $_SESSION['cart'] is the string that gets updated when the user adds a product to the cart.

I use a for loop with

```
${"book$x"} = str_replace("011", "55USD New Traditions and Encounters ", ${"book$x"});
```

to display the book information instead of the numbers for the user. However, I am having trouble with deleting part of the string when the user cancels the item.

The user presses

```
echo '<a href="redirect.php?cancel=' . $x . '">Cancel</a>';
```

and redirect.php looks like this:

```
<?php
        echo "aaa";
        include 'mycart.php';
        $x = $_GET['cancel'];
        $booksnow = str_replace(${"bookid$x"}, "", $books);
        $_SESSION['bookstrings'] = $booksnow;
        echo $_SESSION['bookstrings'];
        header("Location: mycart.php");

 ?>
```

When I go to redirect.php, $_SESSION['bookstrings'] is successfully updated, but when I redirect back to mycart.php, the variable resets.

I don't mind rewriting a lot of stuff, so is there a better way to code the cart? Using a string was the first thing that came to my mind, so built on top of it, but I feel like it's very inefficient, and I would love to use a simpler way with functionality.

PS: when a page opens, the php part does not show up, and when I refresh, it becomes normal. Any ideas?

Comment: the only issue i see here is you are using $booksnow = str_replace(${"bookid$x"}, "", $books); instead of $booksnow = str_replace(${"book$x"}, "", $books); the var should be ${"book$x"} and not ${"bookid$X"}

Comment: @FerminPerdomo ${"bookid$x"} is the same as $"{book$x"}.